# Dismiss notification on low memory?

Tags: android

[image]

As you can see from the picture, this is what happens to my fancy media player notification when the system goes low on memory. This notification is issued from a service and when the system goes low on memory, the service is stopped, too, automatically by the system.

From the behavior, it seems that the `Service`'s `onDestroy()` is not called because it is implemented to get rid of the notification. So, i decided to implement `onTrimMemory()` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int memory){
    Log.d("TRIM", "Please, Trim Memory");
    String stop = getResources().getString(R.string.stopping_playback);
    if(MusicService.status == 1){
        stopService(PodcastrApplication.newInstance().getMusicServiceIntent());
    }
    Toast.makeText(PodcastrApplication.this, stop, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But that did not work. I didn't even see the `Toast` or the Log.

So, how do I remove the notification when the system goes low on memory?

*PS: At the point when this happens, it is certain that the `MediaPlayer` has stopped playing (automatically). It is only a matter of removing the notification.*

Answer (score 1):

When the service terminates, it notifies all its clients about this event. Therefore, the corresponding [ServiceConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) object in the client activity receives a onServiceDisconnected() callback. You can remove the notification from within this method.

EDIT:

```
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection(){

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name){

            ClientActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable({

                public void run(){
                    getSystemService("notification").cancelAll();
                }
            }));
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(...){...}//do something if you need to
};
public void onPause(){        

    Intent i = getIntentForService();
    bindService(i, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
public void onStop(){//or onDestroy()
    unBindService(connection);
}
```

Comment: Okay and where does this go? In the `MainActivity` ? Do I need an `IBinder` or something similar? This is new to me :)

Comment: I thought, because you are using a service, this concept is familiar to you.

Comment: Ok great, read your edit. This will work even when the app is not in focus? The notif is shown when the user presses the `HOME` button :) *Like Google Play Music*

Comment: The `Service` starts when the `Activity` goes **out** of focus so that the user can continue playing the music in background. When the memory is low, the `MediaPlayer` is auto-stopped and the `Service`, too, and the `Notification` goes crazy :)